# Did not work react router in nested

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I made nested router using react router.

I want to go to login page, when to finish sign up successfully.

But, Router didn't work. How can i do for this. Thanks for your help.

```js
// StepTwoComponent.tsx

signUp(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
  userService.signup(this.props.signup).subscribe((res: any) => {
    if (res.result === 'success') {
      this.props.history.push('/login');
    } else {
      alert(res.msg);
    }
  });
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<!--App.tsx-->

<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Redirect exact={true} from="/" to="/login" />
    <Route path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
    <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUpComponent} />
    <Route component={LoginComponent} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>

<!--Signup.tsx-->

<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Redirect exact={true} from="/sign-up" to="/sign-up/1" />
      <Route path="/sign-up/1" component={StepOneComponent} />
      <Route path="/sign-up/2" component={StepTwoComponent} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**EDIT: ADD index.tsx**
index.tsx only has this code.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

Comment: use `BrowserRouter` only once, in the wrapper component, either in index.js file or as per your structure.

Comment: Thanks you. I delete `BrowserRouter` in `Signup.tsx`.
And this work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is you are using `BrowserRouter` multiple times, use only once in the app wrapper component either in `index.tsx` file or as per your structure.

`index.tsx` file:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

And remove `BrowserRouter` from all other components.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use **BrowserRouter** at the top level and not in every subcomponent, Remove it from **SignUp.tsx**. Also `Switch` is not needed in `Signup.tsx` since none of your paths overlap. Switch basically is used to render the first Route match and when none of your paths overlap only the Route which is matching will anyways render

**App.tsx**

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Redirect exact={true} from="/" to="/login" />
    <Route path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
    <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUpComponent} />
    <Route component={LoginComponent} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**Signup.tsx**

```
 <div>
      <Redirect exact={true} from="/sign-up" to="/sign-up/1" />
      <Route path="/sign-up/1" component={StepOneComponent} />
      <Route path="/sign-up/2" component={StepTwoComponent} />
  </div>
```

Comment: If i delete <Switch>, Didn't redirect from '/sign-up' to '/sign-up/1'.
I don't need /sign-up page.

Comment: @Jong-HyenKim did you delete Switch only from Signup component ??

Comment: Yes, I delete Switch only in signup component. Do i delete all?